# Azure Kusto - how to fetch urls from a string using parse

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

```
let T = datatable(Id:int, Text:string)
[
   1, "SomeTextSome TextSomeText:&nbsp;https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844",
   2, "SomeText SomeText&nbsp;<https://someurl.com/fileId/newedit/71244>SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText",
];
T | parse Text with * "someurl.com" myurl ">" * | project Id, myurl 

Output
=========
Id  myurl
1   
2   /fileId/newedit/12702480
```

Need a way to parse Text field and extract url from it. Content of the text field is html body. Using parse works, if there are more characters after the url Id like ">" or blank space, however if the Text field ends with the url id, it doesn't work. Url Id is not fixed length. If not parse, is there any other way to extract everything from someurl.com until the id, irrespective of whether the url is in the middle of the string or at the end?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let T = datatable(Id:int, Text:string)
[
   1, "SomeTextSome TextSomeText:&nbsp;https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844",
   2, "SomeText SomeText&nbsp;<https://someurl.com/fileId/newedit/71244>SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText",
];
T | extend URL=extract('&nbsp;.?(https://[a-zA-Z0-9/.]+)', 1, Text)
```

+1 to Yoni L.'s answer above.   The above will include the https.... not sure if this is what you are looking for.

**Output**

```
URL
1   https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844
2   https://someurl.com/fileId/newedit/71244
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's any knowledge you have regarding the URLs format, you can try including that in a regular expression, and use the [`extract() function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractfunction).

For example:

```
datatable(Id:int, Text:string)
[
   1, "SomeTextSome TextSomeText:&nbsp;https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844",
   2, "SomeText SomeText&nbsp;<https://someurl.com/fileId/newedit/71244>SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText",
]
| extend Url = extract(@"someurl\.com(/\w+/\w+/\d+)", 1, Text)
```

| Id | Text | Url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SomeTextSome TextSomeText: [https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844|/fileId/edit/12649844|](https://someurl.com/fileId/edit/12649844%7C/fileId/edit/12649844%7C) |  |
| 2 | SomeText SomeText https://someurl.com/fileId/newedit/71244SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText | /fileId/newedit/71244 |